# React fetching from API error - let user know what is going on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

API I am using has some limitations and sometimes when I make too much requests, the API won't respond or will respond with an error. The way I handle calls is pretty standard I think. This code illustrates this:

```
const fetchItems = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}&from=0&to=5`);
    const items = await data.json();
    setItems(items.hits);
    console.log(items.hits);
};
```

```
{items
    ? items.map((item) => (
            <FadeInSpring>
                <RecipeCard title={item.recipe.label} image={item.recipe.image} uri={item.recipe.uri.split("#")[1]} />
            </FadeInSpring>
        ))
    : () => (
            <div className="col-6 col-md-4 p-0">
                <h1>NO RESULTS</h1>
            </div>
        )}
```

I have included this conditional statement `items ? (show_items) : (show 'no result'`. In my opinion when `items` list is empty, the code should output 'no results' however it just outputs nothing. Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Empty array is evaluated to "true", that's why you are seeing "nothing" instead of "NO RESULTS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify your ternary operator:

```
items && items.length ? 'RESULTS CODE' : 'NO RESULT'
```

Comment: This one worked like a charm! Big thanks. Now the problem is that it displays `no results` before fetching the data but I have started to read about fetching using `.then` which seem to be solving this issue.

Comment: @ablaszkiewicz1, you can add some kind of loader during the api call is made, check this one https://www.basefactor.com/react-how-to-display-a-loading-indicator-on-fetch-calls